# script to calculate the account balance based on deposits and withdrawals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question with my script, my script is partly well to calculate the specific client, but what I need is to do for all customers without asking the customer data that needs to update its amount, as would be the appropriate code to compute all customers?

Here my script:

```
    DECLARE @RFC VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Nombre VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Apellidos VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @NoCuenta VARCHAR(50)

SET @RFC = ''
SET @Nombre = ''
SET @Apellidos = ''

--Suma de los depósitos
SELECT SUM(Monto) FROM [dbo].[Depositos] a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Clientes] b
ON a.CuentaId = b.ClienteId
WHERE  b.Nombre = @Nombre and b.RFC = @RFC and b.Apellidos = @Apellidos and 

--sum of retires

SELECT SUM(Monto) FROM [dbo].[Retiros] a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Clientes] b
ON a.CuentaId = b.ClienteId
WHERE b.Nombre = @Nombre and b.RFC = @RFC and b.Apellidos = @Apellidos

--Calculation of the total balance on the basis of deposits and withdrawals
DECLARE @Deposito DECIMAL
DECLARE @Retiro   DECIMAL
DECLARE @Total    DECIMAL
DECLARE @NoCuenta VARCHAR(50)

SET @Deposito = (SELECT SUM(Monto) FROM [dbo].[Depositos] a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Clientes] b
ON a.CuentaId = b.ClienteId
WHERE b.Nombre = 'Marco' and b.RFC = 'sadfasfasfadsf')

SET @Retiro = (
SELECT SUM(Monto) FROM [dbo].[Retiros] a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Clientes] b
ON a.CuentaId = b.ClienteId
WHERE b.Nombre = 'Marco' and b.RFC = 'sadfasfasfadsf')

SET @Total = (@Deposito - @Retiro)
SELECT @Total

SET @NoCuenta = '123456'

UPDATE A SET 
Saldo = @Total FROM [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] A 
WHERE NoCuenta = @NoCuenta

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] WHERE NoCuenta = @NoCuenta
```

The tables:

[image: databasebank]

The data of every client:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables ddl statements, some sample data dml statements, and desired result.

Comment: also could you please translate :Recalculo del saldo total en base de depósitos y retiros

Comment: @TheGameiswar Calculation for Total Ammount based in deposits and withdraws.

Comment: You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to prepare a sample data. Use `Text To DDL` to create the schema and load data

Comment: images are blocked ,so if your saldo table has client,then you dont have need to do all steps you are doing

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE CuentasBancarias SET
    Saldo = 
        ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Monto) FROM [dbo].[Depositos] a INNER JOIN [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] ON a.CuentaId = CuentasBancarias.ClienteId), 0) 
        - 
        ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Monto) FROM [dbo].[Retiros] a INNER JOIN [dbo].[CuentasBancarias] ON a.CuentaId = CuentasBancarias.ClienteId), 0)
```